# Xamarin AppCenter.Start() does not exist

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I've been following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin#423-xamarinforms) in order to integrate Microsoft AppCenter in my xamarin.Forms App but it kept throwing error saying:

```
The type or namespace name 'Start' does not exist in the namespace 'AppCenter' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

on calling AppCenter.Start().
Here is my code in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStart()
    {
        AppCenter.Start(
            "ios={Your App Secret};macos={Your App Secret};android={Your App Secret};uwp={Your App Secret};windowsdesktop={Your App Secret}",
            typeof(Analytics),
            typeof(Crashes));
    }
```

Comment: did you add the [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin#41-add-the-using-statements) statements?

Comment: Sure.
'using Microsoft.AppCenter;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;'

Comment: try fully qualifying it `Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.Start(...)`

Comment: tried it already, didn't help

Comment: something is wrong - try deleting and re-adding the packages